# Событие input срабатывает много раз

Tags: javascript

Есть поле, в него вставляется ссылка, на поле также висит обработчик input. Когда вставляешь ссылку первый раз, то событие срабатывает один раз, потом я очищаю поле. И если вставить еще один раз, то событие уже сработает 2 раза, а потом 3

Comment: Без кода непонятно. Покажите, как навешиваете обработчик события.

Comment: Рзаместите пример на jsfiddle.net

Comment: если я правильно помню очистка поля это тоже событие возможно из за этого событие срабатывает многократно наличие кода помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Когда вставляешь ссылку первый раз, то событие срабатывает один раз, потом я очищаю поле. И если вставить еще один раз, то событие уже сработает 2 раза, а потом 3

У вас вешается событие динамически, скорее всего когда вставляете ссылку, или нажимаете на кнопку. Каждое навешенное событие будет вызываться :)